# Italic letter by attaching overline

Tags: italic

I want to make an overline via " $\overline{O}$VERLINE " above a letter but this letter then appears in an italic shape. How do I avoid this?

[image]

Comment: Try with `$\overline{\mbox{O}}$VERLINE`. There's a minor loss of kerning when compared to `OVERLINE`.

Comment: That was fast! :) Thank you very much, works perfectly! How do I mark this question as solved?